# basics of multiple tasks at runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net, rendering, html

i have two things to do

on a button click event i need to

1. show animated gif
2. start long task to calculate or do anything that takes time

though i just made tests to acheive this as i could think

```
void dothings()
{
  showWait();
  doStuff();
}
```

and then

```
void dothings()
{
    Task task1 = new Task(() => showWait());

    task1.Start();

  doStuff();
}

public void showWait()
{
    var img = "<img src=\"images/Earth3_movie.gif\" />";
    DivSerpRes.InnerHtml = img;

}
```

still only when `doStuff()`
is finally done the page renders the animation ...

how could i get it done properly?

Edit

using asp.net 4.0 Webforms

Comment: Are you just trying to show the image while the task is performing?

Comment: @awhitehouse104 now i have made another test in javascript though the problem now is that onclientClick pointing to a javascript function to set innerHTML = "an img html"... though the animation freezes after half a second while code behind is working

Answer (score 1):

i have done it via adding a javascript code using the image button attribute onClientClick

```
onClientClick="setTimeOut(func, 200)"

function func(){
 var Thectrl = document.getElementById('DivWaitImg');
 Thectrl.style.display = "block";
}
```

setTimeOut has somthing to do with pagepostback event freezes the page so it needed to wait 200ms

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure you have this backwards. You want to make the `Task` be `doStuff` and the `showWait` to be non-async. The method in the `Task` is what runs in the background.

Comment: tied that the page went blank somehow as if the task is rendering a blank page, i am now testing another appcroach by using javascript to do that